# Using rest fixture in a scenario to make it reusable

Tags: fitnesse

I have been trying to find if this works.

```
|Script|RestScriptFixture|http://admin:password@localhost:5984/|
```

I found this example but have been getting an error that the restscriptfixture is not found.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not imported the fixture correctly. If you look at the SetUp part of [the ScriptTable documentation](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable), you can see that they include some fixtures to get it to call the actual class. According to [the RestScriptFixture documentation](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture/wiki/LiveDoc), the actual import statement is:

```
|import|
|smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture|
```

Note that you must have the RestScriptFixture jar on your classpath as well.